# MySQL LEFT JOIN that won't work

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have a mysql join and for someone reason its returning duplicate fields for image and firstname and lastname. Like it's not joining right.

Here is the SQL

```
SELECT a.follow_id, a.user_id, a.following, b.firstname, b.lastname, c.firstname,   c.lastname, b.image, c.image
FROM followers a 
LEFT JOIN candidates b ON a.following = b.user_id
LEFT JOIN donors c On a.following = c.user_id
WHERE a.user_id = 222
LIMIT 9
```

Both candidates and donors have a firstname and lastname and image, so I need to get those fields, but not duplicate the fields.

My Results 
[image]

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know I'm not doing this right, please show me the way! :)

Comment: DISTINCT sill returns a table with duplicate columns.

Comment: I'm using LIMIT to limit the result to 9 rows.

Comment: earlier 9 was missing in your query...

Comment: I edited it. Sorry for the confusion. Still returning duplicate columns in the results. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.follow_id, a.user_id, a.following, b.firstname, b.lastname, b.image
FROM followers a 
LEFT JOIN candidates b ON a.following = b.user_id
WHERE a.user_id = 222


UNION DISTINCT


SELECT a.follow_id, a.user_id, a.following, c.firstname,   c.lastname,  c.image
FROM followers a 
LEFT JOIN donors c On a.following = c.user_id
WHERE a.user_id = 222
```

I'm not sure i'm understand your problem correctly.

Comment: See image of results...Duplicate columns

Comment: I just did and it returns two extra rows with only the user_id, and the other fields NULL. Why is it returning two extra rows? There are only two rows of data total.

Comment: Becouse of the left join. If no data found in the donors or candidates table it will return NULL to those fields (this means those users doesen't followed by anyone). Try to use INNER JOIN.

Comment: That did it thanks...I need to brush up on my sql bad. :) +1 from me

Answer (score -1):

Your `follow_id` and `following` fields are unique. Since you are joining to the candidates and donors tables using the unique following field, you will need to create 2 subqueries that pull the pertinent information from each table as well as the user_id from the followers table.

You can then do your joins from your followers table to each subquery:

```
SELECT f.user_id,
       can.firstname,
       can.lastname,
       don.firstname,
       don.lastname,
       can.image,
       don.image
FROM   followers f
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.user_id,
                         a.following,
                         b.firstname,
                         b.lastname,
                         b.image
                  FROM   followers a
                         INNER JOIN candidates b
                           ON a.following = b.user_id) can
         ON f.user_id = can.user_id
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.user_id,
                         a.following,
                         c.firstname,
                         c.lastname,
                         c.image
                  FROM   followers a
                         INNER JOIN donors c
                           ON a.following = c.user_id) don
         ON f.user_id = don.user_id
WHERE  f.user_id = 222
LIMIT  9;
```